# How can i convert a list into a circular list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, circular-list

I have a list `[5, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6]`, I need compare each digit with next to digit, also compare first digit and last digit to each other. Think like that this list is around a circular table. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks now...

Comment: A problem with constructing such circular list, is that many predicates will no longer work on it since they assume "finite" lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just carry on the first element during a recursive visit, stopping at last:

```
compare_adj([First|Rest]) :- compare_adj([First|Rest], First).
compare_adj([A,B|T], F) :-
 writeln(compare(A,B)),
 compare_adj([B|T], F).
compare_adj([Last], First) :-
 writeln(compare(Last, First)).

?- compare_adj([5, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6]).
compare(5,4)
compare(4,8)
compare(8,9)
compare(9,7)
compare(7,6)
compare(6,5)
true ;
false.
```

*edit*

albeit fairly inefficient, we could do combining some builtins, to spare some code:

```
compare_adj([First|Rest]) :-
 append([First|Rest],[First],Temp),
 forall(append(_, [A,B|_], Temp), writeln(compare(A,B))).
```

Comment: Bad edit, IMO! The first variant worked with constraints when replacing `write(compare(A,B))` with `dif(A,B)`... the `forall` variant is broken there and *gives unsound answers without batting an eyelash*...

Comment: @repeat: I cannot see, in question text, from where you get the conviction that dif/2 is what OP needs. So, IMO, your comment and answer are both misleading and useless complicated.

Comment: Fair enough. `dif/2` may well be way off. But the OP definitely wants some intransitive binary relation (or else the circle is pointless and we could use `chain/2`).

Answer (score 3):

It is likely you do not need a circular list—a non-circular one will do...

```
:- use_module(library(lists), [last/2]).
```

How so? Quite straightforwardly: prepend the last item and use "lagging" to enforce your constraint of choice between all adjacent list items.

```
wrapped_adj_dif([E|Es]) :-
   last(Es, E0),
   adj_dif_prev([E|Es], E0).

adj_dif_prev([], _).
adj_dif_prev([E|Es], E0) :-
   dif(E, E0),
   adj_dif_prev(Es, E).
```

Sample queries<sup>1</sup> using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
?- wrapped_adj_dif(Xs).
   Xs = [_A,_B]      , dif(_B,_A), dif(_A,_B)
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C]   , dif(_C,_A), dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_C)
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D], dif(_D,_A), dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_C), dif(_C,_D)
...
```

Notice that above code is deterministic when the first argument is an acyclic ground list:

```
?- wrapped_adj_dif([a,b,c,d]).
true.
?- wrapped_adj_dif([a,b,c,a]).
false.
```

---

#### Edit

If you use the above "wrapped adjacent" access pattern with *different* constraints, consider hoisting the common features! You can cast them into a reusable [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) like so:

```
for_all_wrapped_adjacent(P_2, Es) :-
   last(Es, E0),
   i_mapadj_prev(Es, P_2, E0).

i_mapadj_prev([], _, _).
i_mapadj_prev([E|Es], P_2, E0) :-
   call(P_2, E0, E),
   i_mapadj_prev(Es, P_2, E).
```

Using above meta-predicate
the new definition of `wrapped_adj_difNU/1`
boils down to:

```
wrapped_adj_difNU(Es) :-
   for_all_wrapped_adjacent(dif, Es).
```

Here are above queries again<sup>2</sup>—this time using `wrapped_adj_difNU/1`:

```
?- wrapped_adj_difNU([a,b,c,d]).
true.                                                   % (unchanged)

?- wrapped_adj_difNU([a,b,c,a]).
false.                                                  % (unchanged)

?- wrapped_adj_difNU(Xs).
   Xs = [_A,_B]      , dif(_B,_A), dif(_A,_B)
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C]   , dif(_C,_A), dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_C)
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D], dif(_D,_A), dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_C), dif(_C,_D)
...                                                     % (unchanged)
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1**: 
The [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) answers were post-processed manually for the sake of conciseness and readability.


**Footnote 2**: No need to worry! The answers Prolog gives us have not changed—not at all.</sup>

Comment: ~ isn't there a more generic way to describe this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list in order to compare:

```
comp_list([X|Rest],L) :-
    append([X|Rest],[X],L).
```

Example:

```
?- comp_list([1,2,3],L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 1].
```